# How to implement Date Filtering in From and To fields

Tags: ms-access

I currently have a table which stores dated projects,
these are then listed in the details as seen in the picture.
I have filters which will search individually but I need to be able to search for a date between dates (From and To)

These have no control source and are only used for the filter.

the control I'm am trying to filter is called : "Date_Time_Changed"

the two fields that I am using to filter this are unbound but called "Change_From" and "Change_To".

is it possible so that when these fields have a date inputted, the form will filter to find a date (Date_Time_Changed) that is between them both?

[image]

Comment: Use BETWEEN AND. Or use >=, <= operators. Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html

Comment: thank you! seem to have it to work.